# Unity ARKit: project camera frame on detected plane as texture to render a top down view with second camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, image-processing, shader, arkit

I'm using Unity3D and ARKit and my goal is to project a camera image onto a plane detected with ARKit. So that I can render my plane with a second orthogonal camera in a brid's eye view. The result would be a textured map from top down view. The whole thing doesn't have to run in real time in the first version, it only should work for one frame on button click.
[image]
My current steps are:

1. freeze the frame on button click (ReadPixels to a UI Image)
2. duplicate the ARKit plane mesh, so that the plane is no longer extended and tracked
3. Now comes the problem, how do I get the camera image (which is stored in my UI image) correctly perspectivelly transformed on my plane? Do I have to do the transformation on the texture or in the shader?
   How do I handle the case if the plane is larger than the current camera image? Do I have to crop the plane first? Like in the picture (case 2) only the green area can be textured.

[image]

From the [ARKit plane geometry](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arplanegeometry#topics) I can get the 3d vertices and the texture coordinates of the plane. I also can transfrom the [World Coordinates to Screen](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html), but I'm struggling with how and where to do the image transformation from screen to my detected plane.